# How to decode this 433MHz RF signal?

Tags: arduino, rf, binary, 433mhz, encoding

I'm receiving this RF signal from a temperature only weather station transmitter. But i can't figure out what encoding is being used.

[image]

[image]

I can't seem to decode the binary. In order to rule out noise or interference, this signals are directly from the micro-controller before entering the RF module.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use some ingenuity. Gather more data. What temperature was this transmitted at? Did you try it at other temperatures?

Comment: Is this one burst? @Daniel 's suggestion is good, but before that spend a while web searching with the model number of your weather station.

Comment: Try ramping the temperature slowly to get consecutive values.  Try to figure out if the data repeats, and if so what each burst looks like.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the quick reply, I've checked with multiple temperatures, can't seem to find a link.

Comment: @kabZX Yes, its from one burst, weather station model can't be found and other similar looking units seem to be using Manchester encoding.

Comment: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com is more suitable for this kind of question in which you tell us nothing about the station's model etc. Also "Manchester encoding" is a way of mixing clock with data. It doesn't tell you anything about what those bits mean. Those packets are probably something like http://fredboboss.free.fr/articles/tx29.php I count about 40 bits in your packets too.

Comment: Does this unit transmit only the temperature?  Is it possible that is transmits other things too (it's own ID, for example) ?

Comment: A word of caution: unless you have precision temperature control (like a precision bath in a controlled environment) the temperature measured by the weather station might be different from the temp you measure externally.

Comment: Both frames have 29 impulses. Measure the time between two impulses and see if the distribution makes sense, is it sufficiently distributed to make ones and zero's from it? Are two frames with the same temperature identical? What temperature range is supported? How many bits of data do you need? Consider binary, BCD, 7-segments (one segment per bit) or a different encoding. Consider some synchronisation, preamble, checksum, ...

Comment: Who says it's sending degC, kelvin, farenheit or just some number that the receiver interprets the meaning of?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there isn't sufficient detail provided (make and model of transmitter, time base and amplitude of captured waveforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My analysis:-

Multiply the temperatures by 10 to create integers.

26.9 * 10 = 269 decimal = 100001101 binary

43.8 * 10 = 438 decimal = 110110110 binary

A long distance between pulses is a 1, short distance is a 0. First 8 bits are the header or sync, next 16 bits are the temperature. The group of 8 close together pulses are the upper 7 bits of the 16 bit integer (which are all 0 for both 269 and 438).

[image]

[image]

More examples are needed to confirm whether this is correct or just a meaningless coincidence.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this is correct. The first 4 bits is the checksum, the next 8 bits is serial number, the following 12 bits as you pointed out is the temp and the remaining bits are battery and mode.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is a string of 8 pulses that remain unchanged. I suggest that is a flag for the start of the data. This could be some sort of pulse position modulation or the pulses could be a binary representation. Start by building a circuit to trigger your scope on the first 8 pulses.